# conan packages vs mingwin conflicts how to fix?

Tags: c++, windows, compilation, mingw, portability

I use conan as a dependency manager for a large C++ project. The project was built for Linux and I am porting it to Windows.

Due to this I am compiling with mingwin since that development environment is closer to mine.

However, conan knows it's running on windows and so it downloads windows binaries.

I am finding that although compilation works, linking fails because mingwin binaries and MSVC binaries are incompatible.

I am not sure if I need to try to instruct meson (my build system) to use cl as the compiler, or trick conan to download Linux libraries instead of windows.

Comment: Have you tried building Conan on Windows using your MinGWin compiler?  Use those libraries instead.

Comment: what do you mean by building conan? It is a python package so it;s interpreted. I am confused.

Comment: I'm confused now.  Why is conan downloading libraries?  Python is usually run by an interpreter and doesn't depend on OS specific libraries.

Comment: Conan is a dependency manager for c++ written in python. So it downloads prebuilt binaries froma  cloud server into your machine, targetting your architecture and then passes arguments to the built system so that it can find them.

Comment: Why do you expect to download Linux libraries of you're porting to Windows?
What you need are Windows libraries for MinGW, or even better MinGW-w64 which exists for both Windows 32-bit and 64-bit.

Comment: I don;t think conan has those binaries in their servers :\